# Quais os métodos do Global.asax, quando são disparados e as boas práticas?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Gostaria de saber quais os métodos, quando eles são disparados e qual a melhor aplicabilidade (boas práticas) deles?

Answer (score 5):

O arquivo Global.asax deriva [`System.Web.HttpApplication`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/System.Web.HttpApplication(v=vs.110).aspx). [O fonte dela está aqui](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/FXUpdate3074/FXUpdate3074/1@1/untmp/whidbey/QFE/ndp/fx/src/xsp/System/Web/HttpApplication@cs/10/HttpApplication@cs).

[Os métodos de `HttpApplication` estão aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpapplication_methods(v=vs.110).aspx). Não sei se vale a pena explicar um por um nesta resposta já tendo em mãos essa documentação.

[Veja também a parte de eventos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.httpapplication_events(v=vs.110).aspx), que deve ser ainda mais útil que a parte de métodos.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, porém eu queria algo mais detalhado a nível de arquitetura, principalmente nas boas práticas de aplicabilidade de cada método. Fico no aguardo de uma resposta com um detalhamento nesse nível.

Comment: Então, não sei se vale a pena fazer isso. A documentação está em português e define bem claramente a nível de eventos pra que serve cada método. As boas práticas desta parte são como as boas práticas da aplicação toda. Assim ficaria amplo demais.